# How to display words alphabetically when Xcode keeps throwing nsexception

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have the following code. It results in a sectioned uitableview. However, the words in each section are in reverse order (r before a, x before t). I have tried to use nsdescriptor and selectors in various parts of the code but it results in Xcode throwing nsexception ncsf dictionary invalid selector sent localisedcaseinsensitivecompare. This only occurs when I fiddle with the above - even if I don't add localisedCaseInsensitiveCompare (it works with those instances that are already in place).

Any fresh eyes able to solve this. 
Thanks

```
@implementation RCViewController

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

@synthesize words;
@synthesize alphabetizedWords;
@synthesize wordDictionary;
@synthesize keys;


-(NSDictionary *)alphabetizedWords:(NSArray *)wordsArray {
    NSMutableDictionary *buffer = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i <wordsArray.count; i++) {

        NSDictionary *keyValue = [wordsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *word = [[wordsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Word"];
        NSString *firstLetter = [[word substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString];

        if ([buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]) {
            [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:firstLetter]addObject:keyValue];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:keyValue, nil];
            [buffer setObject:mutableArray forKey:firstLetter];
        }
    }

    NSArray *bufferKeys = [buffer allKeys];
    for (int j; j<bufferKeys.count; j++) {
        NSString *bufferkey = [bufferKeys objectAtIndex:j];
        [(NSMutableArray *)[buffer objectForKey:bufferkey]sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }

    NSDictionary *result = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:buffer];



    return result;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [keys count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *key = [_sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
    return  [wordsForSection count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *key = [_sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
    NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
    NSString *word = [[wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"Word"];


    [cell.textLabel setText:word];

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSString *key = [_sortedKeys objectAtIndex:section];
    return key;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:cell];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        detailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *key = [_sortedKeys objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        NSArray *wordsForSection = [self.alphabetizedWords objectForKey:key];
        NSString *word = [[wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]objectForKey:@"Word"];
        destViewController.word = word;
        destViewController.definition = [[wordsForSection objectAtIndex:[indexPath row] ]objectForKey:@"Definition"];

    }
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"words" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *wordsDictionary = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.words = wordsDictionary;

    self.alphabetizedWords = [self alphabetizedWords:self.words];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    self.keys = [self.alphabetizedWords allKeys];

    self.sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the word and display in cell? Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: No sorry. The words list in reverse alphabetical order - e.g. tom, liam, Adam. I want it to be the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, I was half asleep last night and didn't explain that well. The table sections are listed alphabetically, but the words in each section are in reverse order. How do I reverse this (e.g. section a - Brian, job, Ben, Barry becomes Barry Ben bob Brian). Thanks

Comment: You are calling alphabetizedWords  method to reverse the order of your words array?

Comment: I have posted my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of dictionaries. Dictionaries don't support the compare method. You therefore can't use a selector based sort. You need to use a different sort method, like sortUsingComparator, or a predicate. (There are lots of different ways to sort arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to reverse the position of element of array you could use following

```
NSArray *wordArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Brian",@"Job",@"Bob",@"Ben",@"Robert", nil];
wordArray = [[wordArray reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Your output will be : Robert, Ben, Bob, Job, Brian.